# C++ issues with adding variables to a vector list

Tags: c++, file, vector

I've created a program that reads different text files and stores each file in its own Vector list. However, the vector list proportion of the program is not working. Provided below is the text file im currently working on as well the program itself

Text file

```
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
```

Main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"
#include "implementation.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
readFile();
writeFile();
robotComplexity();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Implementation file containing functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//declaration of parts variables
char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;

std::vector<string> partsVector;
std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

std::string newChar;
std::stringstream convertChar;

void readFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{

   std::string line;

while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    line.pop_back();//removing '.' at end of line
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);

    convertChar << partCode;
    convertChar >> newChar;


    // then read each element by delimiter
    int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {//spilt into different records
      switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count

      case 0:
        newChar = token; //convert partCode from a char to a string 
        break;
      case 1:
        partName = token;
        break;
      case 2: maximum = stoi(token);
        break;
      case 3: minimum = stoi(token);
        break;
        case 4: complexity = stoi(token);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      counter++;//increasing counter
    }

    partsVector.push_back(newChar);

    for(string x: partsVector)
    cout << x << endl;
}

}


double robotComplexity() { 


double complexity;

for(int i = 1; i < partsVector.size(); i++)
/*
if(newChar == "A") {
   cout << "Character: " << newChar;
} else   {
   cout << "Program isnt working! :(";


} */
   if(complexity > 100) {
      complexity = 100;
   }


cout << "\nThe Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
return complexity;
}


double robotVariability() {

double variability;


cout << "\nThe Robot Variability is: " << variability << endl;
return variability;

}

void writeFile() //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations. 
{

}
```

The code that im currently experiencing issues with is the following

```
while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    line.pop_back();//removing '.' at end of line
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);

    convertChar << partCode;
    convertChar >> newChar;

    // then read each element by delimiter
    int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {//spilt into different records
      switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count

      case 0:
        newChar = token; //convert partCode from a char to a string 
        break;
      case 1:
        partName = token;
        break;
      case 2: maximum = stoi(token);
        break;
      case 3: minimum = stoi(token);
        break;
        case 4: complexity = stoi(token);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      counter++;//increasing counter
    }

    partsVector.push_back(newChar);

    for(string x: partsVector)
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

When this program is compiled and executed, the following is printed out to the console

```
A
A
B
A
B
C
A
B
C
D
A
B
C
D
E
```

This is clearly wrong, as it should be printing one of each letter, as required by my program specs.

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

The purpose of this is so i know the function can successfully identify Each Record. To note, this occurs with other varialbes such as partName. Ive deducted that it is an issue with how I'm adding the variables to the vector but I am unsure why. Any help would be great Thankyou.

Comment: Please don't use global variables. Declare the variables in the functions where they are needed and use parameters and return values to pass information between functions. Using globals rapidly makes the code unmanageable as the program gets bigger. If I were your professor you would lose a lot of marks for this. Not quite a fail, but getting close. Work through your code one global variable at a time and move them to the places thay are actually needed.

Comment: @john Apologies. I've rewritten the question to make it easier to read, removing code irrelevent to the question. Hope that helps

Comment: I was hoping you'd fix your code rather than edit your post. Seriously if you don't lose marks for the coding style then your professor is a very lenient person. Aside from the style, your code does show you can manage tricky requirements, it's a lot better than some code we see round here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is simply where you are printing out the `partsVector`, it's inside your reading loop when it should be after the reading loop. So it should be this

```
while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    ...
    partsVector.push_back(newChar);
}

for(string x: partsVector)
    cout << x << endl;
```

instead of this

```
while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    ...
    partsVector.push_back(newChar);
    for(string x: partsVector)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

Because you are printing the parts vector as you read it in, you get those repeated values displayed.

Comment: So i tried fixing it, but i still get repeated Values. Ive added the attempt at the end of my question